# how to websocketSendMessage in spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I need to find a specific websocketsession in spring controller and do session.sendMessage

Below is the error code, but this is the direction I want to do.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        
        websocketSession.sendMessage("message");
        
        return "jsonView";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help you. Is the spring officiel documentation [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/)